# How to sum from 2 different tables based on a criteria in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

So I have 2 data sets. Data set A gives the total staff count as per budget, and data set B gives the total staff count as per deployment. Both data sets mentions in each line for which supplier, cost centre, etc.

I want to create a summary in another table which says for Supplier A, budget staff count is 1000, but deployment staff count is 900. Is there a way to do this? Please please help.

I tried summing up in a different table but it didn't work out as it says Cannot convert value of type Text to type True/False.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data for dataset A and B and finally what output you need?

Comment: Please share sample data.